# In Django, how to create join on either primary keys?

Tags: python, sql, django, orm

So, in Django, we have two models.

```
model1(models):
          pk1 = models.pk(model2, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='fk1')
          pk2 = models.pk(model2, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='fk2')
          some_field = models.charField()

model2(models)
         somefield = models.charfield()
```

I'd like to create a query to join then and match on either the first primary key or the second
The sql equivalent would be

```
select *
from model1
join model2 on (model2.id = model1.pk1__id or model2.id = model1.pk2__id)
```

for now I'm stucked with

```
Model1.objects.select_related('model2')
```

which always match on the first pk

I've tried transversing throught the foreign keys

```
Model1.objects.values('fk1__some_field', 'fk2__some_field')
```

but as you inspect the query, it shoes that it does two joins, naming the second table something like 't6'

Answer (score 0):

Adding a ForeignKey to both models will give you the capability to filter through both tables and query for results. It can be done like so:

```py
key = models.ForeignKey(ModelReference, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

*The ModelReference is the model that the ForeignKey is based on.*

On the other hand, if you want to create a more detailed db relationship, you can add a OneToOne or ManyToMany Fields like so:

```py
field = models.OneToOneField(ModelReference, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
car = models.ManyToManyField(Cars)
```